# How to know if the type parameter is dynamic?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

It seems that every time `dynamic` is used by the caller of a generic method, the type actually used is a simple `object`. For example, the code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Program.DoSomething<int>();
    Program.DoSomething<object>();
    Program.DoSomething<dynamic>();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

public static T DoSomething<T>() where T : new()
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "The type is: {0}; equal to object: {1}.",
        typeof(T).FullName,
        typeof(T) == typeof(object));

    dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
    result.Hello = "Hello";
    result.Number = 123;

    try
    {
        return (T)result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Can't cast dynamic to the generic type.");
        return new T();
    }
}
```

produces:

> The type is: System.Int32; equal to object: False.
>   Can't cast dynamic to the generic type.
>   The type is: System.Object; equal to object: True.
>   The type is: System.Object; equal to object: True.

How is it possible to determine, within the generic method, whether the type parameter is dynamic or an ordinary object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot. Dynamic is all in the eye of the beholder (meaning: the compiler). It is *implemented* as dynamic. You can, however, check for `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`: if an object implements that, the caller is probably talking about `dynamic`. Unfortunately, reflection also works inside `dynamic`, but will not involve `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` at all.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` would be useful if there was a parameter of generic type passed to the method. In my example, only the return value uses the generic type.